# How to show and hide Custom UITableView Header Cell of Table View in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, header

I am developing an application in Swift3 where I have to show and hide UITableView Header for different users. For displaying `UITableView Header View`, I have created a custom class `CustomHeaderCell` of `UITableViewCell`.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 235.0
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderCell

        return headerCell
    }
```

Now Can anyone please help me to hide this Header of my `UITableView`?

Note: I tried using this `tableView.tableHeaderView?.isHidden = true`, but not working. Should I need to do the validation in `heightForHeaderInSection`?

Reference Link to Add HeaderViewCell: http://www.accella.net/knowledgebase/custom-header-and-footer-views-for-uitableviews/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way to differentiate users then you can just change the header height like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if userA {
        return 235.0
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

That should help in hiding the header

Comment: That I know @Prasad, Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @user2786 I don't think so. We could try returning nil in viewForHeaderInSection but that would result in an exception. Since we just want to hide it and not remove it, setting its height to 0 would be the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `tableHeaderView` and section header views, which are differents:

- `tableHeaderView` is a view showed as a header for the whole UITableView
- section header views are reusable views used for displaying header above each section

In your case, you want to use section header views, so you should return empty ones for non concerned users (I assume here `sectionNeedHeader` will be replaced by your condition).

Also, you better use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instead of `UITableViewCell`. The behavior is globally the same but it's made for this usage:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if sectionNeedHeader {
        return 235.0
    }

    return 0.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if sectionNeedHeader {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "HeaderView") as! CustomHeaderView
        return headerView
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for your suggestion, I have multiple of validation. Is this will be only way to achieve this or possible by code also?

Comment: To avoid multiple conditions, you can return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForHeaderInSection function, and use auto layout to set you header view layout (in this case the header view height will be set by the constraints).

More about UITableViewAutomaticDimension here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html